# Setup a content test failed with NullReferenceException

Tags: sxa, content-testing

I am new to Sitecore. We are using `Sitecore SXA and Sitecore 9.3`. I need to set up a simple `A/B rendering test`. When I provide a variation for the test in `Experience Editor` and click ok (see Picture below),

[image]

Then press save button, the page becomes unavailable and throws the **following error**:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object.]
> Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.EvaluateTestExposureBase`1.Process(TPipelineArgs
> args)        (Object , Object )
> Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
> Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
> PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
> Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
> Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
> pipelineName, TArgs args)
> Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
> context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
> step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Does anyone how to fix it? I tried to deploy all Market Definitions, however, it didn't help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could be a Sitecore bug, you should contact Sitecore support for this. There is an `EvaluateTestExposureBase` error related KB article suggesting a hotfix -https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0647546

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the solution was to accept cookie of website. However, to make it work without cookie consent, I think you need to go to support since it is bug of Sitecore (https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0647546).